# Find three functions, each of a different variable, that when added up agree with the given table of values

Tags: mathematics

I have the following set:

| x<sub>1</sub> | x<sub>2</sub> | x<sub>3</sub> | N<sub>x</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 50 | 20 | 83 |
| 30 | 20 | 50 | 79 |
| 45 | 15 | 40 | 74 |
| 65 | 35 | 45 | 72 |
| 50 | 20 | 30 | 77 |
| 55 | 25 | 30 | 79 |

$$f_1(x_1) + f_2(x_2) + f_3(x_3) = N_x$$

N<sub>x</sub> Max = 100, Min = 0 or 50

Goal: N<sub>x</sub> = 100 (what are x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub> when N<sub>x</sub> = 100?)

$$x_1 , x_2 , x_3$$ range 0 to 100, they are inputs into functions $$f_1,f_2,f_3,$$ these functions add together to = $$N_x$$

What equation/function determines the outcome, and how would this be solved? Please show work. I want to solve this problem and also learn how to solve problems like this one.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand how to derive functions from number sets. I am hoping someone can show me how. I had a friend use this as an example trying to explain it to me. He said that each function (f) could have a different input (x) and that there would be a way to find an "optimal point" for each x in each f to make N = 100

Comment: Did your friend make the problem himself?

Comment: I guess this fits better in math stackexchange?

Comment: The functions cannot all be linear functions of the form f(x) = ax + b.  I put the first four equations in the form 30a + 50b + 20c + d = 83 into a solver and the solution for the first four equations doesn't work when we try the numbers for equation five.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer should be a comment, but it's a bit too long for that. Sorry about that.)

With no restrictions on the functions, the question is pretty much meaningless.

To see what I mean, here's an extremely crude way to define the functions so that their sums fit the values in the table, and give $N_x=100$ for $x_1=x_2=x_3=42$:

$f_1(x_1)$: $100$ when $x_1=42$; zero otherwise.
$f_2(x_2)$: $N_x$ when $x_2 \in \lbrace15,25,35,50\rbrace  $; zero otherwise
$f_3(x_3)$: $N_x$ when $x_3 \in \lbrace30,50\rbrace$; zero otherwise

where the $N_x$ means that you look up the value of $N_x$ from the table above.

Comment: I guess we can start with a set of linear equations too if it's not this simple. But yeah, in general it can be pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: So I think each function has 1 x value which will maximize the output 

Basically, there are 3 x values that range from 0 to 100, and they are inputs into 3 different functions. When the correct values are input, the answers of the three functions equate to 100.